# Yii2 Как сделать выборку из Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2, activerecord

Есть таблица **demand** (id,quantity,user_id ...) есть таблица **quality**(id,name), есть связующая таблица **demand_quality**(id_demand,id_quality)

Задача. Нужно взять все записи из таблицы **demand** пользователя от которого сидим и сравнить со всеми другими записями из таблицы **demand**.
Не пойму как сравнить значения из связующей таблицы..

Как сделано на данный момент.
Получаем данные текущего пользователя

```
$demands = Demand::find()->joinWith('demandQuality')
            ->where(['user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->getId()])
            ->asArray()->all();
```

Далее в цикле проходим по массиву подставляем значения которые получили выше и сравниваем. Но в данном варианте сравнение quality проходит как IN(..). А нужно чтобы каждое значение сравнивалось и если есть хоть одно не соответствие запись эту не выводить.

```
     foreach ($demands as $key => $demand) {
                $kor = $demand['price'] * 0.25;
                $min = $demand['price'] - $kor;
                $max = $demand['price'] + $kor;

                $demands[$key]['offers'] = Demand::find()
                    ->joinWith('demandQuality')
                    ->where(["and","price >= {$min}", "price <= {$max}"])
                    ->andWhere(['offer_type_id' => $demand['offer_type_id']])
                    ->andWhere(['quantity'=> $demand['quantity']])
                    ->andWhere(['units_id'=> $demand['units_id']])
                    ->andWhere(['packing_id'=> $demand['packing_id']])
                    ->andWhere(['delivery'=> $demand['delivery']])
                    ->andWhere(['demand_quality.quality_id'=> isset($demand['quality']) ? $demand['quality'][0] : ''])
                    ->andWhere('user_id != :user_id',[':user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->getId()])
                    ->asArray()->all();
     }
```

Как сделать такой запрос?